# Convert WCF To Rest

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am trying to get JSON from a WCF service by url using the following code :

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "players")]
public List<Person> GetResult()
{
    List<Person> results = new List<Person>();
    results.Add(new Person("Peyton", "Manning", 35));
    results.Add(new Person("Drew", "Brees", 31));
    results.Add(new Person("Tony", "Romo", 29));
    return results;
}
```

My `web.config` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
                 type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                                   multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
  ------
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But when I tried to start debugging the WCF service:

```
http://localhost:55636/Service1.svc/players
```

I get a blank page ?

Comment: what browser are you using? IE for example starts downloading json file and shows blank page. Could you please post your web.config as well?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome return blank page , I did not test IE

Comment: Have you checked in the inspector? Especially in the response tab, what are you getting back?

Comment: no thing in inspector

Comment: what's the project type you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `WCF` in browser you need to have defined `webHttpBinding`

```
<services> 
  <service name="yor_name"> 
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" contract="yourservice_Interface"> 
    </endpoint> 
  </service> 
</services>
```

also in `WebConfig`:

```
  <endpointBehaviors> 
    <behavior name="webBehavior"> 
      <webHttp /> 
    </behavior> 
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

For configuration details please follow that:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803009/Configure-WCF-Service-to-REST

Or here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: i do not have services tag on my web.config, do you want me to add it ?

Comment: how are you configuring your endpoints then? WCF = A + B + C (Address, Binding, Contract). Web.config is putting those things together.

Comment: I update the question, actually i did not change any thing on web.config, could you please update my web.config